# PHPword cannot open stream

Tags: php, phpword

I have task that I am loading Tinymce Editor to my browser and edit it. After editing I am trying
to save the editor value into Microsoft format and for this purpose I use Phpword class . I 
include the file path but I can't there is a fatal error said that require_once(../PhpWord.php): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory. I already put the Phpwrd.php in the directory 
that I am tring to access

my code is

```
require_once '../PhpWord.php';
$PHPWord = new PhpWord();

    $section = $PHPWord->createSection();
    // After creating a section, you can append elements:
    $section->addText($data);
    // At least write the document to webspace:
    $$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
```

Comment: `../` means the file is in the directory one level higher than the landing page. is it?

Comment: I use require_once 'PhpWord.php', and I had the same error again!!

Answer (score 0):

The Error you are having is because PHP cannot find "PhpWord.php". the code you gave it - '../PhpWord.php' will look in the parent directory of your current directory.

I have never had any good luck with relative paths and the require statement. PHP prefers a full path when using require_once. If you want to find the file using a full path within your own drectory you will use

`require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/PhpWord.php");`

if you want to look for the file a directory abov, you will use

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/PhpWord.php");
```

I hope this helps. Good Luck!